# Adding a Sideloading App Package (.appx) to a Suite/Advanced UI Project

Tags: installshield, appx, appxmanifest, makeappx

I want to side-load appx using Install shield suite project.
I had referred below link to do so:
http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/SteAppXPackages.htm

I am getting below error during deployment:[image]

I am not able to resolve this.
Need help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain why AppxInstalled would be an invalid condition. Perhaps a debuglog (run your suite with /debuglog) would have more to say. But this is likely explained by the version of InstallShield you're using bring unable to read details from the .appx file you have selected. Ideally that would result in build errors or warnings before a run-time failure, so you can check for those too.

Since you link to the InstallShield 2015 help, I'm assuming that's the version you're using. Unfortunately its support for appx packages is still based on the Windows 8 era APIs and XML schema for Windows Store Apps, and does not work cleanly on Windows 10's changes to UWP. InstallShield 2016 [updated this support](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield23helplib/helplibrary/whats_newIS2016.htm#introduction_2744878416_22803) in multiple ways (see *New UWP Condition Checks added to Suites* for the most relevant ones).

Per comments, you say that InstallShield 2016 didn't address the problem, so it's possible you have a stray AppxInstalled condition that isn't filled out correctly. Take a look at the conditions you have specified on your packages (and actions for that matter, but they shouldn't affect things this early). Or go directly to the built xml that you can find as setup.xml in the Interm folder. Then we can track this condition back to where in the project it originated.

Comment: Thanks Michael.During build not getting any error or warning. Also there is nothing as such in debug log. I have one doubt whether it is related with Package Guid or Display name should match with appxmanifest as seen in image. I tried but not work.Still have doubt for Package Guid.I will try same with InstallShield 2016.Also let me know if you are getting same error.

Comment: If your package is UWP, 2016 should definitely help. Assuming you didn't override it, the default eligibility condition for that package (used also in the suite's mode condition) needs to read the identity of the .appx file, and 2015 doesn't understand the UWP manifest. And, per your experience, apparently it will not issue warnings or errors while failing to read the identity.

Comment: Package is created using MakeAppx tool. So this is not pure UWP.I have tried same with IS2016 Premier,but facing same problem.

Comment: For my earlier point, it's not use of MakeAppx that should matter, but which SDK it's from. Or really, which namespaces are used in your AppxManifest.xml. However if 2016 doesn't fix the problem, it's probably something else. Examine the setup.xml file in your interm folder for AppxInstalled elements, and update your question with more info.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I think IS 2016 resolved the issue. I found package getting installed successfully on RS3 machine. For RCA, need to compare configuration of both system.